# VSDX dont have the Visio Icon in SharePoint 2013 search

Tags: search, search-results, visio

Visio 2013 files (vsdx) dont show the Visio Icon when I use the SharePoint search. Is there an easy fix for that? Adding a result type doesn't work.

Comment: http://www.techmikael.com/2015/09/adding-icons-to-visio-2013-files-in.html

Comment: Thank you, it worked with that script. But you have to keep in mind that the script needs to upload something to your "Site Assets" and it gets that library by its title which is not its actual name, if you don't have your SharePoint farm in English.

Answer (score 2):

You could copy the out of the box Word or PowerPoint display template and improve it. There is a result type rule for "Visio" but it appears to ignore VSDX files. You could even go so far as to produce a hover panel using Visio Services to display a preview of the file! If all you want it the proper icon. I would copy the Office Document display template (Item_OfficeDocument.html) and use the icvsdx.gif icon.

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question, but where do I need to put the icvsdx.gif icon in the Item_OfficeDocument.html? The only line with the word "icon" in it is commented out.

Comment: You have to decide. Have you looked at the other solution posted by Mikael?

Comment: Huh? Yea I did and I tried but it requires me to enter a site URL and I have tried a few but none seems to function.

Comment: I mean you control the entire UI, so you can put it anywhere you like in the HTML. The icon file I mention is in the images directory on every SharePoint farm, so you reference it the source of an image tag.

Comment: I got it now, I used the PowerShell script from techmikael.com. You have to keep in mind that the script needs to upload something to your "Site Assets" and it gets that library by its title which is not its actual name, if you don't have your SharePoint farm in English.

Comment: I believe it uses JavaScript, so you are uploading a script file. Glad it works for you.